# Pandas: after using qcut(data,3), how to find the range of the quantile

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
    spread                              CPB%    Bin  
0  0.00000787  0.001270648030495552731893265565   B  
1  0.00000785  0.003821656050955414012738853503   A  
2  0.00000749  0.005821656050955414012738853503   C  
3  0.00000788  0.004821656050955414012738853503   B
```

So I have basically assigned a letter A,B or C according to the value of their spread. I have done this using this code:

```
s = (df['spread'] * 10**15).astype(np.int64)
df['Bin'] = pd.qcut(s, 3, labels=list('ABC'))
```

What I need to do now, is that I have 100 spreads (from 0.000001 to 0.0001) and I need to know if they end-up in the Bin A,B or C. Is there a way to find let's say the 'range' of the above quantile?

More precisely I have the below spreads:

```
      spread
0   0.000100
1   0.000109
2   0.000118
3   0.000127
4   0.000136
5   0.000145
```

How can I know if they end-up in the same bin as A-B-C of above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df['your_split_col_name'], 3)
```

The output will tell you the bin intervals.

Using the labels masks that.

**EDIT**

To use the created split, you could use pandas groupby function.

```
df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df['your_split_col_name'], 3)
df = df.groupby('bins')
df.describe()
```

Comment: Thanks! And do you know how to cut my new column using the same bins values?

Comment: Once you assign the bins or intervals to the new column, you could use groupby. Is 
 this what you mean by cut new columns? See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need add parameter `retbins=True` for [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) for return intervals, so is possible reuse it in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
print (df1)
     spread      CPB% Bin
0  0.000008  0.001271   B
1  0.000008  0.003822   A
2  0.000007  0.005822   C
3  0.000008  0.004822   B

print (df2)
     spread
0  0.000008 <-change data sample for match
1  0.000109
2  0.000118
3  0.000127
4  0.000136
5  0.000145
```

---

```
s = (df1['spread'] * 10**15).astype(np.int64)
v,b = pd.qcut(s, 3, labels=list('ABC'),retbins=True)
print (v)
0    B
1    A
2    A
3    C
Name: spread, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A < B < C]

print (b)
[7490000000 7849999999 7869999999 7880000000]


s1 = (df2['spread'] * 10**15).astype(np.int64)
df2['new'] = pd.cut(s1, bins=b, labels=v.cat.categories)
print (df2)
     spread  new
0  0.000008    A
1  0.000109  NaN
2  0.000118  NaN
3  0.000127  NaN
4  0.000136  NaN
5  0.000145  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help @jezrael, I might still need your help in the coming hours :p

Comment: @Viktor.w - hmmm, I am going home in next hour, so I think get help from another users in stackOveflow after this time ;)